# Good way to copy ALL files from a Windows drive to external HDD if I don't know where important files may locate?

Tags: hard-drive, backup

My Windows just recently died and now I want to copy all the files from the C: drive to my external HDD. And you might be wondering why all files? Because I'm afraid I might forget something in the copying process. Of course I don't need Program Files folders and Windows folder, because I'm certain there isn't anything important.

So I was thinking, would a simple <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> & <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> would be fine?
Would it be better to do this via terminal?
Does Ubuntu care about hidden files, Windows specific system files?
How would I verify that ALL files got copied without a problem?

Comment: Maybe you should leave all about Windows out and just ask how to copy ALL files from a (directory on a ) NTFS device to an external HDD. Just to make sure it does not get closed for being off-topic. And usually people should do their backups _before_ the system dies... :-/

Comment: For the record I can say `cp -arv` did **not** copy hidden NTFS folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `rsync` command to do this. Copy-pasting is not useful in case your operation fails and you need to resume at some point. Moreover, rsync can tell you what it is doing. The command would be `rsync -azv --progress /old-location /new-location`. If the rsync command fails for some reason, just repeat the command. Rsync will happily move all files, including hidden files. If the rsync command (after a repeat) no longer copies anything, you can be certain that all files have been copied. Only filenames with special characters (like é or ñ) may in some cases be modified.